# Update access column from existing values

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a MS access table with the following columns and sample records.

How do I update the adDate value with the least LastSaleDate for each ProductID.

```
orderID productID   lastsaleDate    adDate
1       1           10/20/2012  
2       1           5/10/2007   
3       1           4/1/2004    
4       1           20/11/2011  
5       2           10/10/2010  
6       2           12/10/1972
```

For example the adDate for ProductID 1 will be 4/1/2004
and for ProductID 2 will be 12/10/1972

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a compelling reason to actually store `adDate` values in your table, consider simply computing `adDate` with a query any time you need it.  That way you don't risk ever displaying `adDate` values which have not been updated to reflect the latest changes to the underlying data.

```
SELECT
    y.orderID,
    y.productID,
    y.lastsaleDate,
    sub.adDate
FROM
    YourTable AS y
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT productID, Min(lastsaleDate) AS adDate
        FROM YourTable
        GROUP BY productID
    ) AS sub
    ON y.productID = sub.productID;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use DMin:

```
UPDATE sales  
SET sales.adDate = DMin("lastsaleDate","sales","productID=" & productid)
```